# Rotate map in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, maps

I'm working with xamarin forms to create an app. I am using Xamarin.Forms.Maps and I want to center the map in one position and then rotate the point of view by keeping the center of the map. In other words, I want to rotate the compass (360 degrees) to change the angle of the view every second, without changing the center of the map.

I center the map:

```
MyMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(this.viewModel.CentroTrasfusionale.Latitudine, this.viewModel.CentroTrasfusionale.Longitudine), Distance.FromMiles(0.14)));
```

---

But If I used

```
MyMap.Rotate(10);
```

rotates the layout of the map, not the point of view of the map

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [Google Maps API](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps).It is support to bearing

```
// No animation
await map.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(
new CameraPosition(
    new Position(35.7104, 139.8093), // center
    17d, // zoom
    45d, // bearing(rotation)
    60d))); // tilt

// With animation
await map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(
new CameraPosition(
    new Position(35.7104, 139.8093), // center
    17d, // zoom
    45d, // bearing(rotation)
    60d)), // tilt
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Comment: bearing and tilt parameters are reversed in Xamarin Android